# how can I create DLL without having class

Tags: dll, windows-mobile

can anyone give me some steps to create DLL without using class which means it will just have methods in the header file and source file would be only DLLmain() plus other methods.  I'm using Visual Studio 2005 to create MFC DLL, but it always generates class.  I never create DLL before but I was told that I can create DLL without class/object oriented concepts, just plain functions.

thanks.

Comment: Don't create an `MFC` DLL. :) `MFC` is all classes, and if you use it you automatically have at least one class. After all, `MFC` means `Microsoft Foundation Class`. Create a plain DLL.

Comment: how can I create plain DLL.  Sorry forgot to mention that I'm building DLL for smart device, Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular Win32 DLL:

In the **New Project** wizard, under **Visual C++** / **Win32**, choose **Win32 Project**.

Then in the next page, choose **DLL** as **application type**.

You may want to select **Export functions** as well to get sample code of exported variables, functions and classes.
From there on, simply delete what you dont need (such as classes).

I no longer have the Windows Mobile SDK installed, but I'm pretty sure you'll find the same kind of wizard to create a Windows Mobile DLL project.

Of course, if you don't want C++ classes, forget about MFC!

Comment: I got it now, thanks.  For me to create an empty DLL project, I have to choose Win32 Smart Device project type, and not MFC DLL type.